# eBay Python SDK Trading API Connection Issue

Tags: python, ebay-api

I'm trying to retrieve the Session ID and FetchToken like the following.

```
import datetime
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection

try:
    api = Connection(appid='APP_ID',
                     devid='DEV_ID',
                     certid='CERT_ID',
                     config_file=None)

    response = api.execute('GetSessionID') # <<===== I'm executing here to understand the response

    # response = api.execute('FetchToken', runame='RUNAME')
    # response = api.execute('GetSellerList', runame='RUNAME')

except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

But when I execute `api.execute('GetSessionID')` to test, I have a connection error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1009, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 871, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 631, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 123, in execute
    self.execute_request()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 193, in execute_request
    allow_redirects=True
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ebay_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

The idea is to retrieve the SessionID and reuse it to call `FetchToken` later and be able to access the other methods from Trading API. But without it working properly I can't do nothing on Trading API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be late, but try this in requirements.txt:

```
lxml
requests[security]
```

see: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3189